# Java while loop subtlety

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I have the following code:

```
while(!loggedIn) {
    loggedIn = login.getDone();
}
System.out.println("madeIt");
```

The print line never executes, even though I know login.getDone() returns true at some point. If, however, I use the following code:

```
while(!loggedIn) {
    loggedIn = login.getDone();
    System.out.println(loggedIn);
}
System.out.println("madeIt");
```

Then the last print line executes. I have no idea why. Does anyone have any insight into why this happens?

For more code, see the entirety of my main class:

```
public class GameManager {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        boolean loggedIn = false;
        String username;
        int playerNum;
        int i = 0;
        Login login = new Login();
        while (!loggedIn){
            loggedIn = login.getDone();
            //System.out.println(loggedIn);                                                                                                                                                                 
        }
        login.close();
    System.out.println("Logged in");
    }
}
```

and the entirety of the login class:

```
import squint.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Login extends GUIManager {
    private final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 200, WINDOW_HEIGHT = 150;

    private JButton login;

    String name;
    boolean done;
    int playerNumber;

    public Login() {
        done = false;
        this.createWindow( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT );
        this.setTitle("Hearts Login");
    login = new JButton("Click");

        contentPane.add(login);
    } 

    public void buttonClicked( ) {
        done = true;
        System.out.println(done);
    }

    public boolean getDone() {
        return done;
    }

}
```

And squint can be found at http://dept.cs.williams.edu/~cs134/squintV2.20.jar

Comment: maybe your program exits before you had a chance to see it ?

Comment: Please include some more of this program for context, specifically the getDone() function.

Comment: The getDone() function simply returns a global boolean variable in the Login. And the program doesn't exit before I have a chance to see it. There is more code after the print line and none of that executes either, the program just loops forever.

Comment: Are multiple threads involved?

Comment: No multiple threads. See edited question for more code.

Comment: You are using Swing UI which means that you have multiple threads even if you did not create a start a thread explicitly, because Swing will create a new event-dispatching thread automatically. So what you have here is a simple data visibility problem in a multi-threaded application. You can verify that assumption by making `done` variable volatile.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loop doesn't see changed value without a print statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25425130/loop-doesnt-see-changed-value-without-a-print-statement)

Answer (score 2):

This could happen if `loggeIn` or the variable that `getDone` returns is set to `true` by another thread and it is not declared `volatile`.

It may be easier to determine your problem if you give a little more code.

Comment: @Cardsox425 - As Oleg says - you are using Swing so there are multiple threads happening behind the scenes. Try setting `done` to `volatile`. I think it will fix your problem.